# Unable to import pdftotext for Python 3.6 on macOS

Tags: python-3.x, pip, package, pdftotext, poppler

I need to use `pdftotext` package for Python.

I have macOS 10.13.3 and I have installed Python 3.6 via Homebrew by command `brew install python3`. Then, as it is stated in [README](https://github.com/jalan/pdftotext), i have installed Poppler by `brew install pkg-config poppler`, as well as `pdftotext` as itself by `pip install pdftotext`.

When i try to load this package in Python by `import pdftotext`, an error is thrown with the following message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "", line 1, in 
>       ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pdftotext.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZN7poppler24set_debug_error_functionEPFvRKSsPvES2_
>       Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pdftotext.cpython-36m-darwin.so
>       Expected in: flat namespace
>       in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pdftotext.cpython-36m-darwin.so

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, so if you have found the solution could you please post

Answer (score 0):

Above error quite common while installing the [pdftotext](https://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html) due to the version mismatch or try to install the [GUI](http://macappstore.org/pdftotext/) apps via brew.& You can try for brew cask.

> brew cask install pdftotext

[Stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4annc.png)

P.S: Homebrew-Cask is an extension to Homebrew to install GUI applications